# EventEmitter memory leak. require('request')

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, request, eventemitter

while using the request module by mikael I'm running the following:

```
if(product.Links.Direct_Link)
{
    var string = product.Links.Direct_Link;
    console.log(string)
    request({'uri': string, 'jar': true, 'followRedirects': false, 'maxSockets': 15, 'headers': { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0"}}, getSizes);
} else {
    callback(null, product);
}
```

this is the output from this:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added.
Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
http://www.spartoo.dk/Palladium_BARROW_KID-x30475.php?sx=G
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:679:33)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:179:8)
    at Request.onResponse (C:\Vuuh\trunk\feedserver\node_modules\request\index.j
s:645:25)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1669:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23
)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1564:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

I'm feeding a lot of http's to this request, as I want it to parse thousands of webpages.

The funny part is that I'm running it on another website and don't get this issue (that site has only 1/10 of the amount of pages though)?

Anyone got a pointer as to why I'm getting an eventemitter warning ? It makes the script run out of memory over time!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of node [#5108](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5108). Upgrade to the latest version(>0.10.11) of node should have solved the issue.

Comment: I'm on `v0.10.22` and i'm getting it.

Comment: I'm too getting it on v0.10.22 , have you worked it out @ThomasReggi ?